# How to run a node without validating the blockchain?

Tags: full-node, validation

How someone can run a node without validating whole Monero blockchain? This can be useful for who wants to run a node on slower disks like HDDs.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (and shouldn't). The primary reason for running your own full node is specifically so you can validate the blockchain. If you're not going to validate, you may as well just use a remote node.

That said, there are a few options you can use to try and tweak/speed-up the syncing:

```
--fast-block-sync arg        Sync up most of the way by using embedded, known block hashes.
--block-sync-size arg        How many blocks to sync at once during chain synchronization (0=adaptive).
--sync-pruned-blocks         Allow syncing from nodes with only pruned blocks
--db-sync-mode arg           Specify sync option, using format [safe|fast|fastest]:[sync|async]:[<nblocks_per_sync>[blocks]|<nbytes_per_sync>[bytes]].
```

Honestly though, the simplest is to just use an SSD, if you're impatient.

Comment: People may still want to validate latest blocks but not older blocks that have been verified over and over by other nodes.